# Blazor UI Update Async void vs Async Task

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly

New to Blazor,

I am working with the Login via API,  however I noticed that the UI doesn't update automatically.

For example:
When I logged in an invalid user for the first time, the error message doesn't display, but on the 2nd try it will display correctly. Somehow has 1 click delay.

```
  private async void DoLogin()
  {
        var result = await API.LoginAsync(username, password);

        if (result.ResultID == 0)
        {

        }
        else
            ErrorMessage = result.ErrorMessage;
  }
```

Razor Component:
[image]

When I changed it to

```
  private async Task DoLogin()
  {
        var result = await API.LoginAsync(username, password);

        if (result.ResultID == 0)
        {

        }
        else
            ErrorMessage = result.ErrorMessage;
  }
```

It is working as expected.

Can someone shed a light

- What's the difference using async void and async Task  in Method signature?
- Why does the async void doesn't update the UI immediately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Polite]You just need to get your head around asynchronous programming.  What's happening is that the UI rendering completes before your asynchronous task.  The void routine `DoLogin` awaits the completion of the API call, but the methods up the call stack don't, there's no Task to `await`.  When the `API` call yields control, it gets handed back up the calling stack.  `DoLogin` waits for the Task completion before completing the rest of the code in the method, but yields to the calling method which then carries on past the call to `DoLogin`- in your case rendering your control.

The `async Void Method` pattern is fire and forget, you get no Task reference to wait on.  `async Task Method` means you can `await Method` in the calling routine.  You can read more [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5276310/Understanding-and-Using-Async-Programming-in-DotNe) in one of my Code Project articles.

Answer (score 5):

> What's the difference using async void and async Task in Method signature?

- An `async Task` (and also just `Task`) return is awaitable, and Blazor will use that.
- An `async void` method is fire-and-forget. It should be avoided where possible.

> Why does the async void doesn't update the UI immediately?

Because it executes un-observed. In this case it runs in parallel with  (but slower than) the code that finishes up after the button. So the UI is updated *before* LoginAsync() returns.